# Django query involving 3 models

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following models:

```
# Part of App called 'core'
class Symbol(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=15)

# Part of App called 'user'
class Position(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol)

# Part of App called 'core'
class Daily(models.Model):

    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol)
    date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
```

Each user can have many positions. Each position is associated with a symbol. Each symbol has multiple records in the daily table. Here is an example of actual data:

User John Smith has a position for symbol XYZ. This symbol has the following entries in Daily:

```
Date:          Price:
01Jan2016      654
02Jan2016      759
```

John Smith also has a position for symbol ABC. This symbol has the following entries in Daily:

```
Date:          Price:
05Mar2016      758
06Mar2016      135
```

What I need is to be able to select all the positions for the current user along with the symbol. I also need to have the latest/newest Daily record for each symbol. The result for John Smith would be:

```
Symbol   Date        Price
XYZ      02Jan2016   759
ABC      06Mar2016   135
```

In SQL (PostgreSQL) I would do something like this (presuming John Smith's user_id is 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (core_daily.symbol_id) core_daily.symbol_id, core_daily.date, 
                   core_daily.price, core_symbol.symbol
FROM core_daily 
JOIN core_symbol ON core_daily.symbol_id = core_symbol.id
WHERE core_daily.symbol_id IN (
      SELECT symbol_id FROM user_position
      WHERE user_id = 1)
ORDER BY core_daily.symbol_id, core_daily.date DESC;
```

I've tried the following Django queries:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Position.objects.all().select_related('symbol').select_related('symbol__daily').filter(user=logged_in_user)
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'daily'.

Position.objects.all().select_related('symbol').select_related('symbol__daily').annotate(Max('symbol__daily_date'))
Cannot resolve keyword 'daily_date' into field
```

The issue seems to be because each Position is associated with one Symbol, however each Symbol is associated with multiple Daily entries (and I just want the latest Daily entry per Symbol)?

**EDIT**

Im getting close with the following:

```
Position.objects.values('symbol__symbol').filter(user=user).annotate(latest_date=Max('symbol__daily__date'))
```

The above query gives me a list containing multiple dictionaries for the latest date for each position, ie:

```
[{'latest_date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 2), 'symbol__symbol': 'XYZ'}, {'latest_date': datetime.date(2016, 3, 6), 'symbol__symbol': 'ABC'}]
```

The only thing I can't get working now is to also have the correct price that corresponds to that 'latest_date', I have tried the following but then the result includes all dates, not just the latest date:

```
Position.objects.values('symbol__symbol', 'symbol__date__price').filter(user=user).annotate(latest_date=Max('symbol__daily__date'))
```

Any suggestions? If not ill just go ahead and use raw sql (which for some reason I thought it was advised to avoid where possible in favor of using regular querysets?)

Comment: Should it not be `symbol__daily__date ` ?

Comment: I still get the error: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'daily'

Comment: you have a raw query. Why aren't you using it?

Comment: @e4c5 I was under the impression you should try to avoid raw queries and use Django's built in queryset functionality as much as possible. If that is not correct please let me know because it's a pain in the a$$. I would far prefer to use raw queries in a lot of cases,...but I thought it was best practice not to?

Comment: I have made some progress. Please see the edit in the original question.

Comment: There is no rule that says raw queries should be avoided. The only time you want to avoid them is when you need to iterate through a queryset multiple times in the same view.